# Add onhover to my page when I display it on smartphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js, onhover

When I use your page from your computer when you hover the mouse over the menu, I received a menu to select the language.

The same thing I want to do when using the hand on the smartphone.

I am Trying to use this Hammer.js, but it does not work. Below my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var languageToChange = $('.lang-list a');
    var change = Hammer(languageToChange).on('tap', function(event){
        alert(event);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't have a `hover` event on a touch screen :) I assume you want it to be `hover` normally, and `tap` on a touch device?

Comment: @Jivings Yes :) I want hover normally and tap on mobile device. How do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should detect width of the screen and if it is under 780px than use tap, otherwise use hover event. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) can help you a lot making resposive site. If you don't want to use it try something like this:

```
function desktopEvent( text ){
    alert( "Desktop:" + text );
}
function mobileEvent( event ){
    alert( "Mobile" + text );
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    var languageToChange = $('.lang-list a');
    var change;
    if ( $(document).width() < 780){
        change = Hammer(languageToChange).on('tap', mobileEvent( event ));
    } else {
        change = Hammer(languageToChange).on('mouseover', desktopEvent( event ));
    }
});
```